# testing text values in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js

Using Mocha, Karma, and React test tools to test the following simple function:

```
renderTodoCount() {
    const { incompleteCount } = this.props;
    const itemWord = incompleteCount === 1 ? 'item' : 'items';

    return (
      <span className='todo-count'>
        <strong>{incompleteCount || 'No'}</strong> {itemWord} left
      </span>
    );
}
```

I'm splitting the test cases up into three cases: 1. `incompleteCount=0`, 2. `incompleteCount=1`, 3. `incompleteCount=2`.

In the first case, I would expect the following output (more or less):

```
  <span className='todo-count'>
    <strong>No</strong> items left
  </span>
```

and would test against that. What I am actually seeing(from `dump()`) is:

```
  <span class="todo-count" data-reactid=".0.0">
    <strong data-reactid=".0.0.0">No</strong><span data-reactid=".0.0.1"></span><span data-reactid=".0.0.2">items</span><span data-reactid=".0.0.3"> left</span>
 </span>
```

Is there a good way to test the value of the text inside of the main span? I'm looking for something equivalent to `.val()` or `.text()` in jQuery.

Comment: `TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass('todo-count').getDOMNode().textContent`

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: Not related to your question, but to do conditional plurals you should do `const itemWord = incompleteCount !== 0 ? 'item' : 'items';`

Comment: interesting, I grabbed that part of the code from a tutorial. why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `TestUtils` that comes bundled with React you can extract the actual DOM node and use the `.textContent` property in order to get the text.

```
TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass('todo-count').getDOMNode().textCont‌​ent
```

Comment: [getDOMNode](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode) has been deprecated btw. It's not `React.findDOMNode(component)`

Comment: Right you are, sir! Thanks!